# Consuming WCF Data Service From Metro Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, microsoft-metro

I'm develping a Metro application, and a WCF Data service hosted in a Windows Service using TCP. The Metro App will use this WCF service to consume data. I get the Windows Service host  running so the WCF Service is available.
 
The problem is that running Metro App to test this configuration in my develop box I get *System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException*. Inner exception is *System.Security.AuthenticationExceptio*n: "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.") , which in turn have this other inner exception too: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "No credentials are available in the security package". 
My Test environment:
Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Device GetDevice(string ip);
}

[DataContract]
public class Device
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Service code:

```
public class WCFDataService : IWCFDataService
{
   public Device GetDevice(string ip)
   {
       return new Device { Name = "Sample device" };
   }
}
```

WCF Service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Apollo.DataService.WCFDataService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="Apollo.DataService.IWCFDataService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/WCFDataService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Metro Application consuming WCF Data Service:

```
var client = new DataService.WCFDataServiceClient();
var peripheral = await client.GetDevice("127.0.0.1"); <-- Throw Exception
```

UPDATE:
If I consume the WCF service from a Windows Form application every thing work fine, so the problem is something with Metro Application.

Comment: Its is the parameter passed to the method, currently I am doing nothing with it.

Comment: So can you just delete it then if peripheral is not going to be used?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point. The IP is  a parameter but for testing purpose I'm just returning a dummy Device. See WCFDataService  implementation above.